# Is there any "Autotune" web service?

Tags: javascript, api, mobile, audio

I want to upload a .wav file on a web service which return my .wav file (or a link to it) with an "Autotune" effect like "I'am T-pain " app for example.

Is there an API to do that ?

I know SonicApi but there isn't Autotune effect :(

I'm using Javascript and it's for mobile device.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Let's start with a clarification: AutoTune is an vocal effects processor from [Anteres](http://www.antarestech.com) that comes both as a plug-in for DAW software and in a hardware version intended for live use. It is by no means the only product on the market with these capabilities.

Conceptually, it is comprised of two functional blocks:

- Pitch detection
- Pitch adjustment

In between these two blocks is an algorithm that maps the pitch detected to a scale note.  This process is called *quantisation*.

Excessive application of quantisation sounds unnatural - particular on the fricative and percussive beginnings of syllables.  This effect, combined with imperfections in pitch adjustment - particularly when the adjustment is large - is commonly (over)used as a production technique and is what you probably have in mind in this question.

As Autotune is a trademark, you're naturally not going to find any online service describing itself as such.

SonicAPI does in fact appear to offer both of the building blocks you require to do this kind of audio manipulation in the guise of the [process/elastique](http://www.sonicapi.com/docs/api/process-elastiqueTune) and [analyze/melody](http://www.sonicapi.com/docs/api/analyze-melody) APIs. 
I imagine you would need to implement quantisation yourself, but this would not be hard.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. Have you got a first step indication to implement quantisation with Javascript? Or a doc ?

Comment: The pitch detection algorithm is going to give you one of frequency or MIDI note number + cents or similar.  There formulae for conversions are [here](http://www.phys.unsw.edu.au/jw/notes.html).   At maximum quantisation you simply round to the nearest scale note - in other words, `cents =0`

Comment: Ok so if i'm not mistaken. I have to proceed like this : Use pitch detection algorithm on my .wav file who will give me (an array of?)"frequency" or "MIDI note number + cent".After that use the formulae for conversions to convert frequency to note. Am i right ? Do you think this work will be compatible with mobile devices ??

Comment: Sounds about right. Can't see any issues with running this on a mobile device other than the upload speed of audio to the SonicAPI service.

Comment: ok ok . I'll give it a try. 1) record sound 2) use pitch detection on the .wav file 3) Convert the frequency to note 4)Create new .wav file with the news notes 4) Upload to SonicAPi ! All that in JAVASCRIPT!! Thanks you. Now i'm ready to start working

Comment: @Thomas would you please consider sharing your discoveries with us? :)